# String replace module definition

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Below I'm trying to replace the `moduleName` string with another string `replacementModule`.

```
var replacementModule = 'lodash.string' // cheeky
var moduleName = 'underscore.string'
var pattern = new RegExp('^' + moduleName + '(.+)?')
var match = definition.match(pattern)
var outcome = replacementModule + match[1]
```

However right now a totally different module is matched as well.

- `underscore.string.f/utils` // desired no change
- `underscore.string.f` // desired no change
- `underscore.string` // => lodash.string
- `underscore.string/utils` // => lodash.string/utils

How can I match to the `/`, and how the outcome that I expect?

Comment: Bingo? `^underscore.string($|/)(.+)?`

Comment: Almost, but not quite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do at least 3 things:

1. Escape the string variable passed to the RegExp
2. Check if `match` is `null` before using it
3. The regex should contain `($|/.*)` as capturing group 1 to match either an end of string or `/` followed by 0 or more characters.

```js
RegExp.escape = function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};

function runRepl(definition, replacementModule, moduleName) {
  var pattern = RegExp('^' + RegExp.escape(moduleName) + '($|/.*)');
  //                         ^------------^               ^------^
  var match = definition.match(pattern);
  if (match !== null) {      // Check if we have a match
    var outcome = replacementModule + match[1];
    document.write(outcome + "<br/>");
  }
  else {
    document.write("N/A<br/>");
  }
}

runRepl("underscore.string.f/utils", "lodash.string", "underscore.string");
runRepl("underscore.string.f", "lodash.string", "underscore.string");
runRepl("underscore.string", "lodash.string", "underscore.string");
runRepl("underscore.string/utils", "lodash.string", "underscore.string");
```

Escaping is necessary to match a literal `.` inside `moduleName` and `($|/)(.+)?` presumes there can be something after an end of string. Also, `(.+)?` (1 or more characters) is actually the same as `.*` which is shorter and easier to read.

Comment: This is perfect I was thinking about escaping as well after I posted this.